# Jhipster on Thymeleaf(Server Side) and Angular(Admin Side)

Tags: angular, thymeleaf, jhipster

I'm working in a monolithic application using Jhipster. The intention is to mix server side Thymeleaf pages for "public" presentation and Angular pages (default generated by Jhipster) for admin side and authenticated user side.

I need server side pages because it's necessary for the pages to be indexed by search engine, and for this purposes I'm working to structure my slug URLs.

For beginning, I change default page:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String indexPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Index");
        model.addAttribute("menu", "index");
        model.addAttribute("header", "");

        return "index-page";
    }
```

It able to show my "index" page, but how I go to admin/authentication mode and calling login page?

Thanks in advance for any help or pointer.

Comment: Just curious to know that why you want to do that..when you can do the same with angular too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. Yes, we are also aware about angular's html5 mode and routing. We are exploring the possibility of "merging 2 worlds" since many modules already done in spring-boot-thymeleaf serverside mode.